# How to pass a character string to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, character

I am trying to process a character string in order to change something in a file. I read from a file a character string which contains a command and an argument, separated by a `space` character. I separated this array in tokens.

Now I want to pass the second token, which is the argument to a function. My problem is that when I run my program, the screen freezes and nothing happens. Here is my separating way and the call to the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void create_file(char *argument)
{
    //some code goes here
}

int main()
{
    int i = -1;
    char *token[5];
    char command[20];
    const char delim[1] = " ";
    FILE *fin;

    fin = fopen("mbr.op", "r");

    while(fscanf(fin, "%[^\n]", command) == 1)
    {
        i = -1;
        token[++i] = strtok(command, delim);
        while(token[i] != NULL)
            token[++i] = strtok(NULL, delim);
        if(strcmp(token[0], "CREATE_FILE") == 0)
            create_file(token[1]);
    }
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where did you set the value of command?

Comment: it is read from an input file, sorry I forgot to add that, modifying the code now...

Comment: `const char delim[1] = " ";` --> `const char delim[2] = " ";` or `const char delim[ ] = " ";`

Comment: use debugger to step into code and determine exact line where machine freezes

Comment: Make sure `i` doesn't go beyond 4 in the loop.

Comment: if command contains more than 5 delim then your program will crash .

Comment: I tryed to comment everything which could cause problems and the I found out that the line where `create_file` is called causes the program to freeze

Comment: Check the result of `fopen`. `operatie` is not declared. You forgot to `fclose`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change the name of that variable; the code is written in my native language and when I pasted it I did not translate that

Comment: These lines: `token[++i] = strtok(command, delim);
        while(token[i] != NULL)
            token[++i] = strtok(NULL, delim);` will make `token[1]` exists if token[0] is not NULL, Is this guaranteed? If it is not guaranteed, then token[1], which is your input to create_file, may point to nowhere.

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed that every line in my input file is like this: _command_ _argument_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors, first `command[20]` is an *uninitialised string* and that will cause *undefined behaviour*. Second, you failed to check the first arg as well as the second, so I added a test where commented. Also, the strings are not long enough so I removed the length. Lastly I test for a `NULL` pointer passed to the function.

**Edit** code was added to the question to show that `command[20]` was initialised, but it is still too short to take the command and a reasonable file name (thanks to @ameyCU).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void create_file(char *argument)
{
    if(argument == NULL)
        printf("NULL pointer\n");
    else
        printf("Arg: %s\n", argument);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = -1;
    char *token[5];
    char command[] =  "CREATE_FILE myfile.txt";
    const char delim[] = " ";

    token[++i] = strtok(command, delim);
    while(token[i] != NULL)
        token[++i] = strtok(NULL, delim);
    if(token[0] != NULL && strcmp(token[0], "CREATE_FILE") == 0)    // added test
        create_file(token[1]); 
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
Arg: myfile.txt
```

Comment: `command` is not initialized but before passing it to `strtok` data is read from file into it using `fscanf` in `while` loop in OP's code .

Comment: @ameyCU that code was added to Q after I began to write the answer.

Comment: Firstly I thought that I had a mistake in the way I pass the character string `token[1]` to the function, but I finally found out that the freezing was caused by an infinite loop in my `create_file` function. However, your security tests and all the other modifications are useful for sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first error is present in array definition:

```
const char delim[1] = " ";
```

In C `""` is a string - an array of characters delimited by `'\0'`. This means that what stands to the right of "=" is a string of two chars:

```
// ' ' + '\0'
//0x20  0x00
```

Therefore this should be an array of two chars:

```
const char delim[2] = " ";
```

or

```
const char delim[] = " ";
```